# Is a ruby_block executed repeatedly when retries is above 0 and ignore_failure is true?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

There is a chef recipe with a ruby-block. The ruby-block is executed until a socket connection can be established (retries 10). In case no connection can be established the ruby-block should not fail (ignore_failure).

Example:

```
ruby_block 'wait for service' do
  block do
    require 'socket'
    require 'timeout'
    Timeout.timeout(2) do
      s = TCPSocket.new('127.0.0.1', 8080)
      s.close
    end
  end
  retries 10
  retry_delay 5
  ignore_failure true
  action :run
end
```

The chef documentation isn't clear about whether the ruby-block is executed repeatedly or not when the `ignore_failure` is set to `true`.

### Update

When the script is executed and no service is listening on port 8080 the execution of the chef recipe continues after the first attempt with the following message:

```
ERROR: ruby_block[wait for service] (cookbook::wait_for_service line 1) had an error: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8080; ignore_failure is set, continuing

...

Error executing action run on resource 'ruby_block[wait for service]'

Errno::ECONNREFUSED
-------------------
Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8080

...
```

Due to the ruby_block declaration I would thing that the ruby is executed 10 times before reporting an `ERROR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your scenario with Chef version **12.19.36** and really it happens that if both `ignore_failure` and `retries` are specified only **ignore_failure** is applied while **retries** is ignored.

Also here Chef documentation isn't clear about this specific scenario and so it is not possible to solve your issue doing that.

Anyway you can solve manually implementing the **retries** and **retry_delay** logic as follow:

```
ruby_block 'wait for service' do
      block do
        require 'socket'
        require 'timeout'

        retry_delay = 5
        retries = 10

        1.upto(retries) do |n|
          err_msg = ""
          begin
            Timeout::timeout(retry_delay) do
              begin
                s = TCPSocket.new('8.8.8.8', 52)
                s.close
                puts("Service is listening on")
                break
              rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
                err_msg = "Port is open but no service is listening on"
              rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
                err_msg =  "Unable to connect to the service"
              end
            end
          rescue Timeout::Error
            err_msg = "Timeout reached"
          end

          if n == retries
            raise "Unabled to reach server in #{retries} attempts"
          else
            puts "Failed to reach server on attempt [#{n}/#{retries}]. Cause is: [#{err_msg}]. Waiting #{retry_delay} seconds and retry."
            sleep(retry_delay)
          end

        end
      end
      ignore_failure true
      action :run
    end
```

You can also improve the code creating a common function **execute_with_retry** with a lambda function as input in order to simply reuse this logic on your recipes when needed.

Comment: Once and only once. I thought the ruby block is executed 10 times even when each attempt fails. But my 'test' shows (simple `puts` before the socket connection shows up only once in the console) when the first attempt fails the ruby block isn't executed again.

Comment: This is because ruby_block content should raise an exception in order to be considered as "failed" and so involve the retries logic. See my update on response.

Comment: To your update: This is a way I also thought about but didn't try and by the way I didn't know how to implement (I'm not that good in Ruby yet). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Anycase this is the approach otherwise the behaviour will be the one indicated on your question. You can test by using my exact code on your recipe replacing yours.

Comment: I updated my question with a console output in case no service is listening on port 8080. For me the ruby_block fails but you're saying it doesn't. I think we're missing the point here. :) In any case your code helped me.

Comment: Is the update on your question produced with my answer's code or with your initial one?

Comment: The initial code. That's why it is an update to the question.

Comment: I had the chance to test directly the scenario in a virtual environment. Check my updated question. It seems the only way for now is a manual approach like the one I shared on my answer

Comment: I can confirm this with chefdk 4.7.73

Answer (score 1):

My test proofs that the retries have no effect. The block is executed only once because the socket connection fails.

Comment: Yes. I confirm this behaviour with Chef version 12.19.36.